# Kotlin - delegate as function argument (anonymous instantiation)

Tags: kotlin, delegates

Is it possible to create an anonymous delegate in Kotlin for the purpose of passing to a function argument?  I'm particularly interested in `by lazy`, but this question probably applies to all delegates.  For example, say I have this function:

```
fun sayHello(name: String){
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

this works just fine:

```
val name by lazy{ "Ralph" }
sayHello(name)
```

But none of the following are correct:

```
sayHello(lazy{"Ralph"})
sayHello(by lazy{"Ralph"})
sayHello({"Ralph") as lazy})
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a practical way to do this for any general delegate. Delegates are designed for use specifically with properties, so their getter implementation takes an object instance (the property owner) and a `KProperty` argument (see [ReadOnlyProperty](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/properties/Interfaces.kt)). They might specifically need these references for their functionality.

The `Lazy` interface happens to have a `value` property so you can use it like this, but this does not apply to all delegates:

```
sayHello( lazy{"Ralph"}.value )
```